# ICE parameters in subsequent SIP Re-invites

Tags: sip, stun

In the ICE rfc 5245 , there is explanation about the subsequent updated offers. But there is no mention as to what should be agent's behavior when subsequent re-invites are sent ?? Should we include ice-candidates ? should we include all local candidates or just default candidates ?

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back about the need for the re-invite. The re-invite is just a protocol formality (for any box in the middle of the connection that might care) and is not usually needed by the two endpoints (which have already negotiated the ICE channels).

As far as I know, he only candidates in the re-invite should be the selected candidates that ICE negotiated (i.e. only the candidate that is actually used).

Comment: What section of RFC 5245 are you referring to?